# CSS background doesn't stretch to the full height

Tags: html, css

I have an element with 100% height. If there are a lot of blocks, then they go beyond it.

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/yPqKa/

How to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.content-background {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.content {
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a min-height on the body :

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body{
    min-height:100%;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/qL87E/1/)**

This will allow the body to adapt it's height to the overflowing content.

Comment: thank you so much, but it doesn't work for my real project, wait a second, I upload it to jsfiddle.

Comment: @owl the issue was not the `min-height`, it was because you are floating the content and it therefore doesn't expand the containers height. to prevent that you need to clearfix the floating content chek the line 14 in the followning fiddle to see the clearfix I added : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/yPqKa/2/ with this technique, you can remove the height on the elements and let them flow automaticaly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have set the height of the html and body elements to 100% of their container, which restricts them to be smaller than the elements they contain. If you remove the `height: 100%;` from the second line, it will work.